# Parsing failure when working with the rethomics (circadian behavior) package in R

Tags: r, parsing

I am having issues both with my data and the test data provided in the rethomics tutorial (https://rethomics.github.io/damr.html#linking) specifically at the linking step. When run the following code, it provides me with the following error.

Code:

```
list.files(DATA_DIR, pattern= "*.txt|*.csv")
setwd(DATA_DIR)

metadata <- link_dam_metadata(metadata, result_dir = DATA_DIR)
metadata
```

Output:

```
row col   expected        actual
  1  -- date like  7/1/2017 8:00

Error: 1 parsing failure
```

I also received a similar error when attempting to apply my own data. This is coming directly from the tutorial, so is there something wrong with the code tutorial or is it something that I have not done correctly. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question *per se*, but I thought I'd throw it out there in case it helps someone who stumbles across this.

Here's how you can create a behavr table in memory, without the disk-based link and load steps: use the behavr() function described at https://rdrr.io/cran/behavr/man/behavr.html

I have some very simple data my PI wanted plotted as an actogram using ggetho (2 variables from a single piece of equipment over time, so, only "one animal").  I wanted to do this in memory where I already had everything, but *all* the tutorials and discussions either already came with a behavr table, or used the link_dam_metadata(), load_dam() kind of stuff; *nobody I saw* talked about how to do it in memory.

I luckily stumbled across this function just as I was getting close to getting it right the disk way....